# How to define a transform in the <defs>?

Tags: svg, transform

I would like to apply a transform to independant objects in SVG and then animate that transform.

I could do it this way:

```
<rect (...) transform="rotate(30)" />
<circle (...) transform="rotate(30)" />
(...)
<path (...) transform="rotate(30)" />
```

But then I'll have to animate each element separately.

What I'd like to do is something like:

```
<defs>
  <transform id="rotation">
    <rotate angle="30" />
  </transform>
</defs>
<rect (...) transform="url(#rotation)" />
<circle (...) transform="url(#rotation)" />
(...)
<path (...) transform="url(#rotation)" />
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the elements in a `<g>` container and rotate that e.g.

```
<g transform="rotate(30)">
<rect (...)  />
<circle (...)  />
(...)
<path (...) />
</g>
```

When you animate the `<g>` transform attribute all the children will rotate

Comment: Thanks, I thought there was a difference between rotating an element in a group and rotating a group. Silly me, duh!